# Check for greater than one nested dictionary for key

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a file that looks like:

```
{"phrase": "can you please talk with Mark and say school/workout/home/homework with slack", "entities": [{ "label": "name", "match": "Mark"}, { "label": "message"}]}
{"phrase": "can you please tweet must_not_put_on_heating_electric_costs_raised_by_\ufffd30pm_as_of_1/6 on whatsapp", "template": "can you please tweet <message> on whatsapp", "entities": [{ "label": "message", "match": "must_not_put_on_heating_electric_costs_raised_by_\ufffd30pm_as_of_1/6"}]}
```

I need to check each row of the file and see if the "entities" key has more than one nested dict. If it does then I need to access that dict and add a match column so the file looks like:

```
{"phrase": "can you please talk with Mark and say school/workout/home/homework with slack", "entities": [{ "label": "name", "match": "Mark"}, { "label": "message", "match": "school"}]}
{"phrase": "can you please tweet must_not_put_on_heating_electric_costs_raised_by_\ufffd30pm_as_of_1/6 on whatsapp", "template": "can you please tweet <message> on whatsapp", "entities": [{ "label": "message", "match": "must_not_put_on_heating_electric_costs_raised_by_\ufffd30pm_as_of_1/6"}]}
```

I'm really not sure how to do this?

my code so far:

```
for row in data:
    entities_len = len(row['entities'])
    if entities_len >2 :
        try:
            row['target_entities'][1]['match'] = 'test' 
            print(row)
```

This isn't populating the second match as expected.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Read a line. Call `json.loads()` or `ast.literal_eval()` to parse it into a dictionary. Then check the length of `d['entities']`

Comment: Thanks will try that.